# EDI x12 Segment Conditions

Tags: conditional-statements, requirements, edi, x12

Keep in mind that I started to tackle EDI standars a couple of days ago only so there are still a lot of nebulous things.

In an EDI segment (like CUR), when a condition is declared (P0304) it states that if one is use, the other should too.

What do them mean by "use"?

Does it mean that the field has to be present in the segment or does it have to have a value in it? Can it be empty but still "used"?

i.e. : CUR*SE*CAD**01

Would it be valid, since CUR03 is in the segment?
Or would it be invalid because CUR03 is empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the ANSI X12 standard, some elements are conditional, based on other elements being present.  For example, in the PID segment, if you send the PID01, you must send either the PID04 or PID05.

An element's "state" can vary from version to version (although it is not that common).  An element that is optional in 3060 **might** be mandatory in 4010.  You didn't state what version you're working with.  A quick view in EDI Notepad seems to indicate the segment structure as you've posted is fine per the ANSI standard.  Your implementation guide (what your partner actually wants) might suggest otherwise.

If you have sample EDI data, download [EDI Notepad](http://liaison.com/products/integrate/edi-notepad) from Liaison.  It's completely free and will do some of the basic standard syntax checking for you.  They also sell a Dictionary Viewer, which is quite helpful, but not free.  Here is the start of an 810 document with the CUR as you described (in version 4010).  EDI Notepad reports no errors.  The CUR03 is simply an empty element.

```
BIG*20130131*746331*20130130*0026074***DI
CUR*SE*TES**01
N1*BS*KEYSOURCE MEDICAL INC*11*RK0236403
```

Comment: Thx. Btw, the question wasn't really related to any release as it is a general application of the term "use" in every release.

I was just wondering if "empty" could be considered as "use".

Thank you for the EDI Notepad. I'll give it a try.

Comment: No problem.  More simply put then, is that the CUR03 is not used.  But the placeholder is still there per the standard, because CUR04 is used.

Answer (score 0):

Use means that there is data in the element.

Not used means 'empty' or 'no data.'